# Query timing out / making query more efficient (exacttarget)

Tags: sql, performance, exacttarget

Here is my query, can anyone see any way to make this more efficient so it doesn't time out?  I'm using Exacttarget (Salesforce Marketing Cloud).  It has a 30 minute timeout limit.  I've tried moving things around but it always seems to error.  I'm kind of a beginner with SQL but I've been hitting it fairly hard the last week.  My query is below.  THanks!

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Email,  c.FName
FROM ENT.Contacts c WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN ENT.RegistrationData r WITH(NOLOCK)
ON c.Email  =  r.RegistrationContactEmail
LEFT Join ENT._Subscribers s  WITH(NOLOCK)
ON c.Email =  s.SubscriberKey
AND s.status NOT IN ('unsubscribed','held')

WHERE

(
    (
        (
            (
                r.RegistrationEmailOptStatus  =  '1' AND
                r.RegistrationEventType  =  'Wedding' AND
                r.RegistrationEventRole IN ('Bride','Other','Bridesmaid','Mother Of the Bride') AND
                r.RegistrationCountry IN ('USA') AND
                r.RegistrationEventDate < '2014-05-31'
            )

            OR

            (
                r.RegistrationEmailOptStatus  =  '1' AND
                r.RegistrationEventType  =  'Prom' AND
                r.RegistrationEventRole ='Prom' AND
                r.RegistrationCountry IN ('USA') AND
                r.RegistrationEventDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'
            )
        )

        AND

        (
            (
                c.Email IN
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT 
                        s.SubscriberKey AS Email
                    FROM 
                        _Open s
                    WHERE
                        datediff(mm,s.EventDate, getdate()) <= 3
                )
            )
            OR
            (
                c.Email IN
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT 
                        s.SubscriberKey AS Email
                    FROM 
                        _Click s
                    WHERE
                        datediff(mm,s.EventDate, getdate()) <= 3
                )
            )
        )

    )

    OR

    (
        r.RegistrationEmailOptStatus  =  '1' AND
        r.RegistrationEventType  =  'Wedding' AND
        r.RegistrationEventRole IN ('Bride','Other','Bridesmaid','Mother Of the Bride') AND
        r.RegistrationCountry IN ('USA') AND
        r.RegistrationEventDate BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-05-31'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Karl that your main performance hit is in the sub-query that references the `_Open` and `_Click` system data views.  But, based on my experience with the ExactTarget (Salesforce Marketing Cloud), you are limited to only running 'SELECT' statements and will not be able to declare a variable this way.

I recommend running a separate query on the `_Open` and `_Click` data view and then reference the resulting data extension in your query.  This may require more steps. But, you'll find the overall processing time is less.

For the first query, I would create a data extension of everyone that has either opened or clicked in the last 3 months.  And then in the second query, I would reference the resulting data extension with a "IN" statement.  This will eliminate one of the "OR" conditions in your query, which can be expensive.   If the query still preforms poorly, I would suggest re-writing the conditional logic on the `RegistrationData` data extension in a way to a avoids "OR" conditions.

**Query1:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.SubscriberKey AS Email
FROM  _Open s WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE datediff(mm,s.EventDate, getdate()) <= 3

union all

SELECT DISTINCT s.SubscriberKey AS Email
FROM _Click s WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE datediff(mm,s.EventDate, getdate()) <= 3
```

**Query2:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Email,  c.FName
FROM ENT.Contacts c WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN ENT.RegistrationData r WITH(NOLOCK)
ON c.Email  =  r.RegistrationContactEmail
LEFT Join ENT._Subscribers s  WITH(NOLOCK)
ON c.Email =  s.SubscriberKey
AND s.status NOT IN ('unsubscribed','held')
WHERE  
(
    (
        (
            (
                r.RegistrationEmailOptStatus  =  '1' AND
                r.RegistrationEventType  =  'Wedding' AND
                r.RegistrationEventRole IN ('Bride','Other','Bridesmaid','Mother Of the Bride') AND
                r.RegistrationCountry IN ('USA') AND
                r.RegistrationEventDate < '2014-05-31'
            )

            OR

            (
                r.RegistrationEmailOptStatus  =  '1' AND
                r.RegistrationEventType  =  'Prom' AND
                r.RegistrationEventRole ='Prom' AND
                r.RegistrationCountry IN ('USA') AND
                r.RegistrationEventDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'
            )
        )

        AND

        (
            c.Email  in (
                select s.SubscriberKey
                from OpenOrClickDE s
                where s.SubscriberKey = c.Email            
            )
        )

    )

    OR

    (
        r.RegistrationEmailOptStatus  =  '1' AND
        r.RegistrationEventType  =  'Wedding' AND
        r.RegistrationEventRole IN ('Bride','Other','Bridesmaid','Mother Of the Bride') AND
        r.RegistrationCountry IN ('USA') AND
        r.RegistrationEventDate BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-05-31'
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I am able to get it to run pretty quickly using 2 queries.  Was just trying to see if there was a better way I could write it in one query.  I do think a UNION is probably the track I need to follow.  Appreciate you taking the time to look at this!

Comment: Hey @Lukacko, if this answers your question, please mark it appropriately.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a shot. There maybe some minor stuff, but the only thing that looks to me like it should make the query spin a long time is

```
            c.Email IN
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT 
                    s.SubscriberKey AS Email
                FROM 
                    _Open s
                WHERE
                    datediff(mm,s.EventDate, getdate()) <= 3
            )
        OR
            c.Email IN
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT 
                    s.SubscriberKey AS Email
                FROM 
                    _Click s
                WHERE
                    datediff(mm,s.EventDate, getdate()) <= 3
            )
```

There are two issues in there. First you are doing date math a bajillion times and second using IN (SELECT ...) here is almost certainly inefficient.

To address the first, calculate a single test date to and use that. For the second prefer checking with EXISTS.

```
DECLARE @testDate DATE = DATEADD(mm,3,GETDATE())
```

...

```
        EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM _Open s WHERE s.EventDate>@testDate AND c.Email = s.SubscriberKey)
     OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM _Click s WHERE s.EventDate>@testDate AND c.Email = s.SubscriberKey)
```

You could also probably unwind the EXISTS and use joins to _Open and _Click, but that feels more complex.

Give this a shot and let us know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you!  Unfortunately, the version of SQL that Exacttarget uses does not allow for variables.  I did get some advice to use a Union on the open and click data above the WHERE clause so I will probably try to see if I can get that to work.  Appreciate you looking at this though!

Comment: I wonder if that would be the case--not familiar with ExactTarget, but I took a flyer. If ExactTarget allow parameterized queries you could calc the test date separately and pass it in. However, you'll probably still see a perf improvement if you you only my second suggestion, while leaving the date calc in line.